# How to let eshell remember sudo password for two minutes?

Tags: eshell

In a general term runing `bash`, when I run a `sudo ...` command, bash will remember my password for a while. This makes package management task easier.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get update
# password ......
sudo apt-get install turing-brain
# execute without requiring password again.
```

Is it possible to accomplish it in eshall?

(I know `term` or `ansi-term` in Emacs can do this. But eshell integrate better with Emacs.)

Answer (score 18):

First of all check which *sudo* is executed in your eshell session.
It can be your system’s sudo:

```
$ which sudo
/path/to/system/wide/sudo
$ which *sudo
/path/to/system/wide/sudo
```

or eshell’s sudo:

```
$ which sudo
sudo is a compiled Lisp function in `em-tramp.el'
$ which eshell/sudo
eshell/sudo is a compiled Lisp function in `em-tramp.el'
```

> Eshell’s [sudo](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html#Built_002dins) uses TRAMP's su or sudo method. These commands are in the eshell-tramp module, which is disabled by default.

I will cover eshell’s sudo case, because it is internal to Emacs and it does not depend on your OS distro:

1. Load eshell-tramp module:

   ```
   (require 'em-tramp) ; to load eshell’s sudo
   ```
2. Switch to eshell’s sudo

   - by prefering built-in commands

     ```
     (setq eshell-prefer-lisp-functions t)
     ```

     It seems that in Emacs 24.4 we need to set

     ```
     (setq eshell-prefer-lisp-variables t)
     ```
   - by creating an [alias](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Aliases) (execute snippet in eshell)

     ```
     alias sudo 'eshell/sudo $*'
     ```

     > Aliases defined (or deleted) by the alias command are automatically written to the file named by *eshell-aliases-file*, which you can also edit directly (although you will have to manually reload it).
3. Finally enable password caching for eshell’s sudo (and TRAMP):

   ```
   (setq password-cache t) ; enable password caching
   (setq password-cache-expiry 3600) ; for one hour (time in secs)
   ```

PS If you have changed your prompt with *eshell-prompt-function*, then remember to adjust prompt regex *eshell-prompt-regexp* accordingly. Wrong prompt regex can break some eshell functionality — including password detection.

Comment: After following these instructions, ```which sudo``` still displays ```/usr/bin/sudo``` on my system.

Comment: Did you test it with a *fresh* eshell buffer? IIRC current eshell session will not pick up changes.

Comment: Yes. I restarted emacs daemon and open a new client.

Comment: After shallow testing I see that (setq eshell-prefer-lisp-**variables** t) is required in emacs 24.4. @Boccaperta-IT can you confirm if it works for you?

Comment: Not working, still ```/usr/bin/sudo``` (I'm using Emacs 25.0.50.1, though)

Comment: I tested that with a fresh Emacs 24.4 w/o any config and w/ fresh HOME directory and it works. I will not test development version. Make sure to test it w/o your config or try to use second method with explicit alias for *eshell/sudo* (I adjusted my answer for that). Good luck.

Comment: No worries, the alias solution works. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about 24.4 but on Emacs 25, `password-cache-expiry` is in seconds, so the comment on your code should read `; for one minute`.

Comment: Yes, it is in seconds. Thanks for pointing that out. Cheers.

Comment: This answer works, but I did not need to switch to the TRAMP version of `sudo` / `su` to get the password caching stuff to work; all I needed was for those variables to be set (and they were by default).

Answer (score 7):

To get sudo working in Emacs 26 (probably the same for Emacs 25) without making an alias I had to add `eshell-tramp` to `eshell-modules-list`.

```
(add-to-list 'eshell-modules-list 'eshell-tramp)
```

Comment: also need to `(require 'esh-module)`

Comment: @nymo looks like we no longer need `(require 'esh-module)` with recent versions of Emacs (27.1+, I think) (I also updated TRAMP to the latest release through GNU ELPA in case that has anything to do with it).

Comment: I've simply added

`(add-hook 'eshell-load-hook (lambda () (add-to-list 'eshell-modules-list 'eshell-tramp)))` and it's sufficient to get everything running whenever eshell is started.